# Explain the Circular Error Probable formula mentioned in this article

Tags: probability, statistics

Metin Bektas in [this blog post](https://metinmediamath.wordpress.com/2013/10/10/missile-accuracy-cep/) writes about how we could calculate the probability (p) of hitting a target by a missile with a given accuracy (measured as CEP) as below:

```
p = 1 – exp( -0.41 · R² / CEP² )
```

Definition of CEP (Circular Error Probable) taken from [the blog post](https://metinmediamath.wordpress.com/2013/10/10/missile-accuracy-cep/):

`An important quantity when comparing missiles is the CEP (Circular Error Probable). It is defined as the radius of the circle in which 50 % of the fired missiles land`.

How was the formula for p derived?

Comment: Using 2D (isotropic) gaussian distributions.

Comment: @Did could you please elaborate. What is the constant -0.41?

Comment: This is odd, the formula in the blog post gives 33% chances to hit the disk of radius CEP. To get 50% chances, one should use $p=1-\exp(-0.69\cdot R^2/\text{CEP}^2)$ instead. Typo?

Comment: The value $0.69$ ($=\ln2$) is confirmed by the French [WP page](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erreur_circulaire_probable).

Answer (score 1):

The formula is a variation on the cumulative density function (CDF) of the Rayleigh probability distribution as found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rayleigh_distribution):

$$F(x,\sigma) = 1 - \exp(-\frac{x^2}{2\sigma^2})$$

where $\sigma$ is the mode of the distribution.  To represent the formula in terms of the radius corresponding to a 50% probability, or $CEP^2$, you would need to use the formula as given by user "Did" above.  I agree that the referenced blog post is incorrect.